# Fitting an image inside a bootstrap column using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently making a grid system, 4 columns wide. I want to have a unique picture inside every column, but I have a issue that it doesnt fit, and when i try max-width: 100% the picture shrinks and gets really small.

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="Bilder/test.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
 /* parent */ .row { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%; }

/* child */ 

.col-sm-3 {  
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 7em;
    margin: 1%; /* important, margin between columns */ 


    color: #FFF;
    background-color: hsla(195, 60%, 50%, 1); }

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-right: 15%;  }
```

Example of how the column look after i added bootstrap class "img-responsive":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm2Ml.jpg

Comment: Can you make a functional demo?

Comment: which version of bootstrap?

Comment: Also...you seem to **not** be changing the width of the columns...

Comment: Setting up a codepen or some demo would be useful.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pavxEP

Comment: Used a random image, but you get the idea

Comment: Remove the padding from the `col-sm-3` divs. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pavxWr

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the padding you have applied.

```
.col-sm-3 {  
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 7em;
   }
```

7em is 112px on either side of the image leaving on 76px (300-224) for the image to fit in.

Remove the padding and the problem is solved.

```css
  /* CSS for "idretter" */


/* parent */

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}


/* child */

.col-sm-3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1%;
  /* important, margin between columns */
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: hsla(195, 60%, 50%, 1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    ...
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem with the image being so small. However, how do I now fit this inside the columns? I've tried width: 100% and object-fit: contain; but nothing works

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven As Paulie explain, the problem is still the padding, and based on if your CSS render before or after Bootstrap's CSS, and the fact that Bootstrap has predefined paddings on `col-*` classes, you might need both a reset and use !important, e.g. `padding: 0 !important;`